What predators are in Afrotheria or coexisted with them while Africa was an island?
I have read (mostly from wikipedia) that while Africa was separated by water from the rest of the world the Afrotheria underwent convergent evolution to produce species similar (or at least equivalent) to many species outside Africa.  However I didn't see any mention of large predators.
Are there are any large predators in this group, or alternatively what were the large predators that they co-existed with before the arrival of Laurasians?

Apologies if the tags I selected are a bit random.  Please edit if there are better ones.

Did you look at the Evolution of Mammals linked from the Afrotheria page? It has a pretty clear tree that might help you understand. Look at the clades with the animal groups and recognize that Afrotheria weren't the only animals on the continent at the time.

I think the question implies that I know that.  I'd still appreciate some examples.

Ah, I should learn to read more, my apologies... I thought you were thinking that they were the only mammals on the continent. It might be helpful for you to expand on what you know about this - i.e. what other mammals you know were there and time timings of the breakups of Gondwana and the various sub-continents from that.

Thats an interesting question! Recently, I stumbled over a group called "Ptolemaiida", which recently have been placed to the Afrotheria. They are wolf-sized carnivorous mammals. However, one should mention that they are quite poorly understood in general (in fact, it is even not completely clear whether they were really carnivorous). Besides this, I am not aware of "large" predators within the Afrotheria. (Of course, striclty speaking, many afrotherians are carnivorous, since the group includes many insectivorous animals, but I assume you referring to big predators).

Besides this, there were also many "Creodonta" in africa, which during the Oligocene were the dominant predators of the continent. The Creodonta are related to the Carnivora (so they are Laurasiatheria), but not their ancestors. Furthermore, they are probably polyphyletic, i.e. consisting of different not closely related groups.

@G.Blaickner, thanks!  If you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it.

@TomV Your welcome! I added an answer.

As suggested by the OP, I transform my comment(s) into an answer (plus some extensions and sources):
Let me first recall the timing of Africa as an isolated continent: The supercontinent Pangaea began to split into two parts during the Late Triassic period (around 230 million years ago), namely into

Laurasia in the Northern Hemisphere (North America, green land, and
the majority of modern Eurasia)
Gondwana in the Southern Hemisphere (South America, Africa,
Antarctica, Australia, New Guinea, India, Arabia, and Madagascar)

By the Early Jurassic (about 180 million years ago), Gondwana started to break apart. Following the mid-Cretaceous (Albian–Aptian) separation from South America approximately 100 million years ago, the African continent remained isolated until the early Miocene (about 20 millionen years ago), when Afro-Arabia collided with Eurasia.
As you probably know, Afrotheria, one of the three major groups of placental mammals (alongside Boreoeutheria and Xenarthra), is thought to have diverged from other mammalian lineages around 100 million years ago. Today, most afrotherians are found in Africa, suggesting an African origin for this clade. However, it's important to note that the earliest known afrotherian fossil, Ocepeia, dates to only about 60 million years ago, so there is a significant gap between molecular clock estimates and the fossil record (but the same is also true for the other groups, like for the Xenarthra for instance).
The Afrotherian group primarily includes large herbivores, such as Proboscidea (elephants, mammoths, and their relatives) and the extinct Embrithopoda, as well as smaller insectivores, like Afrosoricida. The only known predatory afrotherian group are the extinct Ptolemaiida, which were wolf-sized animals that lived in northern and eastern Africa during the Paleogene period (late Eocene to Miocene). However, not much is known about these animals. (in fact, they have only recently been placed to the Afrotheria)
However, while Africa was an isolated continent for more than 70 millionen years, as noted in this very nice article,

The isolation of Africa was broken intermittently by discontinuous filter routes that linked it to some other Gondwanan continents (Madagascar, South America, and perhaps India), but mainly to Laurasia. Interchanges with Gondwana were rare and mainly “out-of-Africa” dispersals, whereas interchanges with Laurasia were numerous and bidirectional, although mainly from Laurasia to Africa.

So, you see, that there have been some interchanges between Africa and other continents, also before the connection between Eurasia. In particular, during the Pleistocene, the Laurasiatherian group Creodonta where the dominant carnivorous placentals during the Palaeogene period, in the near
absence of carnivorans (see also this article). Creodonts, once thought to be the direct ancestors of modern carnivores, were among the first mammals to adopt a predatory lifestyle after the age of dinosaurs. They are now considered to be a polyphyletic assemblage consisting of two groups

Oxyaenidae: bear- or cat-like animals with short limbs and
robust bodies, adapted for climbing and ambushing prey, mostly found in North America and Asia.
Hyaenodontidae: More widely dispersed animals with longer,
lighter bodies, similar to modern wolves or hyenas. They appeared
earlier in Africa and Eurasia.

Last but not least, let me note that besides mammals, there also have been other predatory animals in former times. For instance, there are records of Phorusrhacidae ("terror birds") in Africa, see for instance this article.
